# Express node.js error: unknown filter ":javascript"

Tags: node.js, express, instagram

I am following the documentation from here:
**https://github.com/Instagram/Realtime-Demo**

Successfully installed all the libraries, however got this error on `localhost`
unknown filter ":javascript"

The attached screenshot URL is the output when I hit the `localhost` in browser.

Any one has similar experience? How to fix? Very much appreciate!

screenshot:
**http://cl.ly/image/2N1M2f1p240n**

Answer (score 0):

The demo is quite old, the `:javascript` filter doesn't exist anymore.

Replace this:

```
:javascript
  | socket.connect();
  | $(document).ready(Media.positionAll);
```

With this:

```
script
  socket.connect();
  $(document).ready(Media.positionAll);
```

(although I can't guarantee that you won't run into any other problems)